# Error installing Kivy on Windows: Provider: x11(['window_sdl2'] ignored) Couldn't connect to X server

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, pip, kivy

I'm trying to install Kivy on Windows10, 64 and I always face the same error:

```sh
$python main.py 
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in /home/kk391035/.kivy/logs/kivy_21-07-26_1.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v2.0.0
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "/mnt/c/Users/pedro/Downloads/edh-life-counter/kivy_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kivy/__init__.py"
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.8.10 (default, Jun  2 2021, 10:49:15)
[GCC 9.4.0]
[INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "/mnt/c/Users/pedro/Downloads/edh-life-counter/kivy_venv/bin/python"
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 186 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_pil (img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: x11(['window_sdl2'] ignored)
Couldn't connect to X server
```

I'm currently following the [kivy installation guide](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/gettingstarted/installation.html#install-pip). I did:

```sh
python -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools virtualenv
source kivy_venv/bin/activate
python -m pip install kivy[base] kivy_examples
```

I've also tried installing all the kivy dependencies:

```sh
pip install kivy[base,media,full,dev,tuio,gstreamer,angle,sdl2,glew]
```

I tried on a virtual environment and on my pc environment using Visual Studio Code.

I also tried to enter those commands from [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bMHK6NDVlCM&list=PLzMcBGfZo4-kSJVMyYeOQ8CXJ3z1k7gHn) video and it doesn't work:

```sh
python -m pip install --upgrade pip wheel setuptools
python -m pip install docutils pygments pypiwin32 kivy.deps.sdl2 kivy.deps.glew
python -m pip install kivy.deps.gstreamer
python -m pip install kivy.deps.angle
python -m pip install pygame
python -m pip install kivy
```

In my virtual environment this is my Python version:

```sh
$python --version
Python 3.8.10
```

In my pc those are my Python versions:

```sh
$python --version
Python 2.7.18

$python3 --version
Python 3.8.10
```

Can you please guys help me. I tried to look in the Internet and I found nothing to help me!

Comment: I don’t understand why sdl2 window provider is ignored, it should be the first choice, can you run with `python main.py -d` to get the debug output? 
Wait, it seems you are in /mnt, are you installing kivy in WSL? i don’t think that’ll work, unless you install some X11 emulator for window that can provide a connection to wsl, but don’t try to do that, it’s not worth the pain, just install kivy in a windows python, not one in WSL (ubuntu).

Comment: You are my hero <3 It worked! I used the Ubuntu(WSL) terminal on my VSCode. I used PowerShell and now it works perfectly! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem. My solution: Update wsl in PowerShell (admin) via *wsl --update* and refresh by shutdown: *wsl --shutdown*